# Dealing With Futre and Past Dates and Times with JavaScript Date Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am trying to get future and past dates programatically based on the current time. I am not sure if I am just dumb or I am truly doing something wrong. So I have 2 questions

Does Node.js or the V8 engine have getMinutes, getMonth, etc... in it? I ask because when I try them I get a `has no method` errors for each of them with regards to a Date object?

Second question is: is there a resource I have missed on how to deal with dates in Node/V8 that I have just missed somewhere?

At the end of the day I am trying to get a date object that is from an hour ago and an hour into the future. Also 5 minutes ago and 5 minutes in the future. It doesn't seem like it should be that hard, but I have been spinning my wheels for a couple of hours now.

Also do it without a 3rd party javascript module.

Here is one, of many, attempt with little luck:

```
var d1 = Date();
console.log(d1);
console.log(d1.getMonth());
```

error:

```
TypeError: Object Sun May 13 2012 20:28:01 GMT-0500 (CDT) has no method 'getMonth'
```

Another example this time from REPL: (Should this not be "march 3 2012 at 3:03:03")?

```
d1 = new Date(2012,3,3,3,3,3)
> Tue, 03 Apr 2012 08:03:03 GMT
```

Comment: If you post your code we might be able to help you. Which methods `Date` objects have can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I was about to post the very same link as Felix. I just tried most of the methods using the REPL - worked fine for me!

Comment: I added some code of something that doesn't work in an attempt to show.

Comment: `var d1 = new Date();` <-- the **new** keyword

Comment: try using `new Date()` Worked for me, whereas it didn't w/o the `new`

Comment: If you call `Date()` without `new`, you get back a string. That's also in the big note in the MDN documentation: *"Note that JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a `Date` object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript `Date` objects have no literal syntax."*.

Comment: Does it auto adjust the hours based on the timezone because seems like it should be 03 and not 08 for hours.

Comment: @percent20—New dates are created in the current timezone, so if you are GMT-5 then 08:03:03GMT will be 03:03:03 where you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the [Date constructor is called as a function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.2), it returns a string, not a date object. Change your code to:

```
var d1 = new Date();
```